# Print the value of the array in a new line every 20 times

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have to make a program in which 200 random numbers between 1 and 100 are generated.

```
    // Create an array to generate 200 numbers
    int Numbers [] = new int [200];

    // Create an array to split the numbers up into 5 categories
    int Count [] = new int [5];

    // Start a new loop
    for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
        // Generate numbers between 1 and 100
        Numbers [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 100) + 1;
    }

    // Sort the array from least to greatest
    Arrays.sort(Numbers);
```

Here is where the problem I'm having starts (I believe).

Every 20 lines, the program should display a new line and then continue on with printing the rest of the numbers.

My issue is that is seems like not all of the numbers are printing... I'm only getting a total of 190 numbers printed out of the 200 that were generated.

```
    // Start a new loop
    for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) { 
        if (i % 21 != 0) {
            System.out.print(Numbers [i] + " ");  
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(Numbers [i] + "\n");
        }
    }
```

I would  really appreciate it if someone could please help me out with the code on this.

Comment: If you must print a new line every 20 number, why do you use i % 21, and not i % 20? Also, please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with lowercase letters: `numbers`, and not `Numbers`.

Comment: Also, don't write `Numbers [i]` and `Math.random ()`. Remove the whitespace that precedes these opening bracket and opening parenthesis on your code, it just hinders readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your condition should look like

```
if (i % 20 != 0 || i == 0)
```

You should put a new line if `i % 20 == 0` but not in the first case (`0 % 20 == 0`)

---

### Simplification

```
for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(Numbers[i] + (i%20 != 0 || i == 0 ? " " : "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please use `println` or `System.lineSeparator()` (because `'\n'` isn't the line separator on every platform). You also need to use `% 20 == 0` for every 20th number. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i % 20 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(Numbers[i]);
}
```

**or** using a ternary like

```
for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i % 20 == 0 ? System.lineSeparator() : " ");
    System.out.print(Numbers[i]);
}
```

Finally, by *convention*, Java variables start with a lower case letter. So please rename `Numbers` to lower case like `numbers`.

Comment: Wouldn't that better be `if (i % 20 == 19)`, to put a return at the *end* of each sequence rather than the start? (And the spaces as well I see - *after* printing the number, not before.)

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= Numbers.length; i++) {
        //
        if (i >= 19 && i % 20 == 0) {
            //
            System.out.print(Numbers[i - 1] + "\n");
        }

        //
        else {
            //
            System.out.print(Numbers[i - 1] + " ");

        }

    }
```